# A name for a drop down

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

In my HTML dropdown when the drop down is loaded I want to show something like "Click" and on clicking it should show the options. By default the first option comes as selected. In place of that I want a custom name which is not part of the option list.

Here is an illustration of what exactly am trying to do.

1. On load the drop down comes like this:
   [image: On load the drop down comes like this]
2. On click on the drop-down it should be this:
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done by

```
<select>
<option value=''>Click</option>
<option value='Saab'>Saab</option>
<option value='Mercedes'>Mercedes</option>
</select>
```

Then you can check with PHP or javascript if the value for the dropdown is set.